# Group by Like SQL Query in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I have a table for example:

```
head1     head2      head3
x         1          BLA
y         2          BLA
z         3          BLA
```

I want to be able to do Group by function liek SQL:

```
    select count(head2) , head3
    group by head3
```

And the output will be something like:

```
3          BLA
```

iv'e been told that i able to do this only on the server side but I want to do that on the client side.

the table is in format of HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head2</th>
      <th>head3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>BLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>y</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>BLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>z</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BLA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do it on both sides, but doing it on the client side will be harder and more troublesome. Secondly you would have to pass to your function column type also. So I would lisen to your friends advise and do it by ajax call and make whole operation on the backend.

Comment: You can't do an sql query in html ? You do SQL queries in sql. You haven't tagged sql in the question.

Comment: I agree with the comments above, if you want to do sql, do it in sql, means on the server, not at the client side, anyway. there are some libs which offer sql like syntax and methods in JavaScript. For example: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html.

Comment: @axel.michel from your experince do you know how heavy it is on the client side? (I mean the sqlike)

Comment: @user3592113 that surely depends on the amount of your data, and the format you provide it (e.g. scanning an html table is more expensive than array or json based approach), but since I don't have any experience with that lib, I can't say.

Comment: @axel.michel I will check this in the next few days because the data are changeable, sometimes 10,000 rows or more and sometimes it's 5 rows so it depend. Thank You very much!

Comment: Ten-thousand rows client side? Eek. I hope that's faceless. Careful if you try to tie that to a template (your `css`, `jquery`, `html`, and `razor` tags scare me a little, since *none* of those are part of your question). Anyhow, can you tell us what format the table's in on the client? JSON? An html table (cringe)?

Comment: @ruffin it a html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just for fun...

```
function countByGroup(data, val)
{
    var i, count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        if (val === data[i].head3)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

var payload = [
    {
        head1: "x",
        head2: 1,
        head3: "BLA"
    },
    {
        head1: "y",
        head2: 2,
        head3: "BLA"
    },
    {
        head1: "z",
        head2: 3,
        head3: "THER"
    }
];

window.alert(countByGroup(payload, "BLA") + " BLA");
window.alert(countByGroup(payload, "THER") + " THER");
```

[Fiddleige.](http://jsfiddle.net/j2ec36by/)

There's no, nice, LINQ-like or SQL-like way of doing it.  If you want to be able to change column name, we can do that too, but, again, **it depends on what your data looks like on the client**.

If you wanted to know more than one `val` type each time, you'd want to edit the function to check for more than one `count` at a time, otherwise you're looping needlessly.

And, again, please be careful sorting tens of thousands of rows of data if it's tied to your UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

OK!

I watched @ruffin answer and I just changed it a little for my own case:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head2</th>
      <th>head3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trtest">
      <td>x</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>BLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trtest">
      <td>y</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>BLA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trtest">
      <td>z</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>THER</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var payload = [];

function countByGroup(data, val)
{
    var i, count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        if (val === data[i].head3)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


for(i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByClassName('trtest').length ; i++)
{
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.head1 = document.getElementsByClassName('trtest')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML;
    obj.head2 = document.getElementsByClassName('trtest')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
    obj.head3 = document.getElementsByClassName('trtest')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
    payload.push(obj)
}

window.alert(countByGroup(payload, "BLA") + " BLA");
window.alert(countByGroup(payload, "THER") + " THER");

</script>
```

this worked for me very good for this current case.
Thank you all!